# Can anyone see what I am doing wrong in the ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, systemd

Got the following odd error with ansible lint and I can't for the life of me figure out what we did wrong, it's probably something incredibly stupid but there you go.

```
ansible-lint -p disable-beats.yml

Couldn't parse task at disable-beats.yml:5 (conflicting action statements: systemd, __line__
     

The error appears to be in '<unicode string>': line 5, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

(could not open file to display line))
{ 'name': 'disable auditbeats',
  'skipped_rules': [],
  'systemd': { '__file__': 'disable-beats.yml',
               '__line__': 7,
               'enabled': False,
               'name': 'auditbeat'}}
```

the following is the contents of the file checked with linter:

```
---
- hosts: linuxservers
  tasks:

    - name: disable auditbeats
      systemd:
        name: auditbeat
        enabled: no
```

Comment: try shifting `-name....`  and the following two places left.

Comment: changed the column reported to two columns less....

Comment: And?? What happened after that?

Comment: @P.... Sorry?   I did the shift and got the same error but rather than saying the error appearing to be in column 7 it said column 5.   Same/Similar playbook is not showing any tasks when targeted to a server (I assume because of the issue lint it tripping over)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [known issue](https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-lint/issues/892) with `ansible-lint`; upgrading to a more recent version such as [5.0.12](https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-lint/releases) will make that go away. If it doesn't for your case, you can either comment on that issue or open a regression at which time you should **provide the versions** you are using

Comment: Thanks for the info,  I am seeing an issue actually trying to run the playbook (more complex version (more beats to shut down).   In that case no tasks were showing up.  I expect its related?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow; you are seeing that same `__line__` behavior while actually executing the playbook, too? Because your question shows only ansible-lint, and while I had seen ansible-lint behave that way before, I've never seen ansible-playbook behave that way

Comment: Thanks for the reply.    So.   My bad on not providing the versions.   We were having an issue with the ansible-playbook command but that was an error on our part (We had tags specified on the invocation and had no tags on the tasks in this playbook (reused some code we had and forgot about the fact the other playbook used roles and the role usage included tags.  I correlated the two issues in my head. Its working now and I think you identified the linter issue.  will accept your answer.